# wp_dropdown_categories initial value

Tags: categories, options, dropdown

I am currently pulling in an option drop-down of a specific category using:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('child_of=20'); ?>
```

I would like the initial value of the drop-down to say 'Bedrooms' and not be the first category.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the initial value of categories drop down by passing category id to selected parameter of wp_dropdown_categories function as shown in following code :

```
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'child_of' => 20,
    'selected' => get_cat_ID( 'Bedrooms' )
) );
```

For more information on this visit [this code page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories).